# Contact form db plugin customization

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I am using contact form db plugin. Now I want to just hide the short code menu link from admin panel.

Is it possible?

Comment: Please use the shift button on your keyboard to capatalize the first letter of a sentence. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [remove_submenu_page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_submenu_page) function to remove the shortcode menu. Pass the parent menu's slug and the submenu's slug as arguments to this function.

Paste the following in your theme's `functions.php` file.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_short_code_menu' );

function remove_short_code_menu() {

    remove_submenu_page(
        'CF7DBPluginSubmissions',   // $parent_menu_slug
        'CF7DBPluginShortCodeBuilder'   // $submenu_slug
    );
}
```

Comment: Yes. It can be removed. Identify the corresponding submenu's slug and pass it to `remove_submenu_page`.